# How to scale rectangle with Kivy using mousewheel?

Tags: python, widget, kivy, mousewheel, scatter

Using python and kivy, I want to translate(drag with mouse) and scale up/down using mousewheel a rectangle drawn in a canvas of a scatter widget.

I am using ubuntu and kivy 1.11.

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch,disable_on_activity')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.graphics import (Color, Rectangle)
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix


class World(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.do_rotation = False
        self.scale_min = .1
        self.scale_max = 10
        self.top = 500

        with self.canvas.after:
            Color(0, 1, 0)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.bbox[1])

        self.bind(pos=self._update_rect, size=self._update_rect)

    def _update_rect(self, instance, _):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.bbox[1]

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print("on_touch_move:", touch.profile, touch)
        return super().on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("on_touch_down:", touch.profile, touch)
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("on_touch_up:", touch.profile, touch)

            if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
                print ("is_mouse_scrolling")
                if touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                    print("scrolldown")
                    mat = Matrix().scale(.9, .9, .9)
                    self.apply_transform(mat, anchor=touch.pos)
                    return True
                elif touch.button == 'scrollup':
                    print("scrollup")
                    mat = Matrix().scale(1.1, 1.1, 1.1)
                    self.apply_transform(mat, anchor=touch.pos)
                    return True

        return super().on_touch_up(touch)

class ScatterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return World(size=(400, 400), size_hint=(None, None))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScatterApp().run()
```

So far, I am able to translate the rectangle with the mouse. Then I can scale up/down the rectangle with the mousewheel. But then I am not able anymore to translate the rectangle.

It seems that using mousewheel re-enable multitouch_sim ?
Note that at the beginning I disable multitouch_sim:

```py
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch,disable_on_activity')
```

Comment: I think you just need to remove both `return True` statements from your `on_touch_up()` method to allow the `Scatter` base `Widget` to complete its touch processing.

Comment: @JohnAnderson You are right. I removed `return True` and it works. Thanks you. You can make an answer if you want or I will do it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, whenever you implement event handling methods that over-ride a super class methods, you should call the over-ridden methods using `super()`. When you do a  `return` without calling `super`, you may be short-circuiting something that that base class is doing. There are situations where you might want to replace the base class handling, but you need to study the base class(es) methods to determine if that is feasible. So, in your particular case, I think you just need to remove both `return True` statements from your `on_touch_up()` method to allow the `Scatter` base Widget to complete its touch processing.